# An algebraic expression for a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I am teaching myself math, and I have a question involving writing trigonometric expressions as algebraic expressions:

Write $\cos(\tan^{-1}(u))$ as an algebraic expression.  The "correct" answer, according to the student solutions guide that I am using, is: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}.$$

The answer I came up with, although more messy is: $$\frac{1/u}{\sqrt{(1/u)^2 + 1}}.$$

To make sure my answer was aligned with the book's answer, I used 2 as a test case for $u$ which makes the answer $\sqrt{5}/5$ or $0.447213596$.

Does it matter what answer I choose, is there a grammar guideline I should follow when solving problems such as this and future mathematical identities?

Comment: I am new to using this forum and I do not know how to properly display numbers in square roots so I used the notaction "sqrt()" to symbolize square rooted numbers or expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Here is a quick explanation of how to typeset mathematical expressions on math stackexchange using MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have edited your question, please check that I have not butchered any of the expressions. By the way, you can click on the *edit* button to see how I formatted math.

Comment: What happens when you use $u=-2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following diagram using the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ explains why the preferred expression is

$$\cos(\arctan(u))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$

and the reason the result is always non-negative even when $u$ is negative.

Recall that for all $u$

$$ -\frac{\pi}{2}<\arctan u <\frac{\pi}{2}$$

and that therefore

$$ 0<\cos(\arctan u)<1 $$
[image: cos(arctan u)]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I have a difficult time interpreting math and your answer though initially intimidating, provided a clear understanding of my mistake.  Thank you for taking the time to demonstrate your solution using the unit circle.

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes a picture really is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the simpler expression is preferred.

Your expression,
$\dfrac{1/u}{\sqrt{(1/u)^2 + 1}}
$
is the same as your book's,
as can be seen by
multiplying both 
the numerator and denominator
by $u$:

$(1/u)u = 1$
and
$\sqrt{(1/u)^2 + 1}u
=\sqrt{((1/u)^2 + 1)u^2}
=\sqrt{1+u^2}
$.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the immediate answer.  You are spot on with your edit.  Your answer leads me to another question.  Can you explain why I can multiply by 'u'?  I understand that you did so to make it match the book's answer,  but what if I did not have a predetermined answer to compare.  Are there mathematical rules that allow such?

Comment: @CarrotPatch as a general technique, multiply your fractions by whatever necessary to eliminate fractions inside fractions.

Comment: Actually, the two expressions are equivalent only for $u\ge0$ since $\cos(arctan u)$\ge0$.

Comment: You can always multiply by one, and$\frac{u}{u} = 1$ if $u \ne 0$.

Comment: @martycohen The point is that OP's result gives a negative value when $u$ is negative and $\cos(\arctan u)$ is never negative.

Comment: @martycohen Note that when $u<0$ then $\frac{u}{u}=\frac{u}{-\sqrt{u^2}}$.